# Counting unique elements in sections of .csv columns (Python)

Tags: python, csv, counter

I have a .csv file of geological formations and occurrences of fossil species at each formation. Each fossil has its own row in the .csv file, with the formation name included in that row.

The code I wrote below printed out the number of formation occurrences just fine.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

out=open("BivalviaGRDWIS.csv", "rb")
data=csv.reader(out)
data.next()
data=[row for row in data]
out.close()

formations = [] 

for row in data:
    if row[13]=='':
        continue
    else:       
        formations.append(row[13])

print Counter(formations)
```

However, there may be duplicate fossil names that will ruin the count; I only want the number of unique fossils at each formation. What can I add to count unique elements in a section of a single column from a .csv file, rather than all elements?

Comment: What column holds the location?

Comment: By location, I mean formation. The formations are held in the 14th column.

Comment: You are doing a lot of redundant work in your code, btw. Why not loop **directly** over the `csv.reader()` object? Instead, you are creating a list of the rows first (in a round-about way).

Comment: And to clarify; you only want to count a formation if you have not yet seen that specific fossil at that formation, right?

Comment: I only have basic knowledge of Python, this is from the csv module tutorials!

Comment: yes, only if the specific fossil has not been seen.

Comment: so what column or columns define the 'specific fossil'? Given a fossil 'foo', and formations 'spam' and 'ham', you want to count both 'spam' and 'ham' if you see 'foo, spam', 'foo, ham', but not count 'spam' again if 'foo, spam' was found in the file again.

Comment: formation "foo" has "spam, spam, ham". I want to count 2: spam, ham.

other formation "eggs" has "spam, ham, ham, ham". I want to count 2 again.

End result printing, "foo :2, eggs: 2" or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of what fossils you have already seen, per formation. A [`collections.defaultdict()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) makes coding that easiest; it keeps a `set` per formation we can test against:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

FOSSIL = 0   # fossil name is the first column (?)
FORM   = 13  # formation is the 14th column

with open("BivalviaGRDWIS.csv", "rb") as inputfile:
    data = csv.reader(inputfile)
    next(data)  # skip header

    seen = defaultdict(set)

    counts = Counter(
        row[FORM]
        for row in data
        if row[FORM] and row[FORM] not in seen[row[FOSSIL]] and not seen[row[FOSSIL]].add(row[FORM])
    )

print counts
```

The above code 'streams' your CSV rows in one generator expression straight into the `Counter()` object; no intermediate data is kept.

Each row is tested to:

- see that the formation column is not empty
- see that the formation was not yet recorded for the given fossil
- record the formation for the given fossil

I've assumed that the fossil name is in column 0; you didn't specify how to extract the fossil name in your question.